# How to compute the difference between two numbers using a weighted formula?

Tags: probability, statistics

Currently at work we use the formula $((\text{expected}-\text{actual})/\text{expected})\times100$ to show the difference between two numbers, however, this formula shows extreme differences for small numbers. For example, in the case of $2$ and $1$ it generates $50\%$ while for the numbers $1004$ and $1000$ it generates $0.4\%$.

Is there a formula that can be adjusted to be less sensitive for small numbers while returning a $((\text{expected}-\text{actual})/\text{expected})\times100$ calculation for larger numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution, ignoring the effect on larger numbers, is to take your two numbers $x,y$ and compute $(e^x - e^y)/e^x$ instead of $(x-y)/x$. If the numbers are small this will return a value somewhere close to the range $[-1,1]$ instead of giving wild answers.